# Update composite column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just want to fill column7 of my_table with values from other columns so the result for column7-value looks like that: 86|WWB|2014  or 86|WWB|- in case that column3 has value 0. Here is my SQL:

```
UPDATE public.my_table
SET column7 =   
case when column1 IS NULL then '-' else column1 end   
|| '|' || 
case when column2 IS NULL then '-' else column2 end    
|| '|' || 
case when column3 = '0' then '-'  else column3 end 


error: invalid input syntax for integer: "_"
```

The problem ist the last case-row, because column3 is integer. 
Column1 and column2 are bpchar, column3 ist int2.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are having type collisions.  It is easy to convert in Postgres:

```
UPDATE public.my_table
    SET column7 = (coalesce(column1::text, '-') || '|' || 
                   coalesce(column2::text, '-') || '|' || 
                   (case when column3 = 0 then '-' else column3::text end)
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks!, the problem with the integer ist solved. For column values [NULL] of column1 and column2 the '-' ist added yet, e.g. -|-|2014, but when the column value is '', the result looks like this: ||2014. I suppose for the coalesce operator the '' is a 'normal value'

Comment: @user615993 . . . An empty string is not the same thing as a `NULL` value.

Comment: OK, thanks, then I should use "    case when column1= '' or column1 is null then '-' else column1 end " instead of coalesce, if I want to catch both  NULL and '', i suppose

Comment: @user615993 . . . Yes, that might be the logic you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using `concat` will make this a lot easier to read and it automatically converts everything to text. However the case statement needs to yield the same data type for all branches, so a cast to `text` is still needed for `column3`

```
UPDATE public.my_table
  SET column7 = concat( 
                   coalesce(column1, '-'), '|'
                   coalesce(column2, '-'), '|'
                   case when coalesce(column3,0) = 0 then '-' else column3::text end
                );
```

Comment: thanks!, the problem with the integer ist solved. For column values [NULL] of column1 and column2 the '-' ist added yet, e.g. -|-|2014, but when the column value is '', the result looks like this: ||2014.  I suppose for the coalesce operator the '' is a 'normal value'